# how to await a promise in a function before getting to next line

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How to wait the `getstatus(statustable).then(function(response)` to do before going to `console.log("old");`  where getstatus is an async function will return a new promise

```
    var count = "old";
    
     getstatus(statustable).then(function(response){
        console.log("changeing count")
        count = "new";
        console.log(count)

    });
    
    console.log("old");
```

Comment: use `async-await`

Comment: Can you explain how this is related to React, because there maybe a useful answer that involves state but your code doesn't show it.

Answer (score 1):

Put `console.log("old");` inside `.then`. Anything you want to execute for sure after the promise you will have to put it inside the `.then` or another `.then` chained after it.

If you want to write it in a sequential way you will have to use [async/await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function).

Answer (score 0):

You can await on getStatus

```
    var count = "old";
    
    await getstatus(statustable).then(function(response){
        console.log("changeing count")
        count = "new";
        console.log(count)

    });
    
    console.log("old");
```

The whole function that this is a part of will need to be async.
If you can't change the function to async then you'll need to do as @Tushar Shahi suggested and put the last console log inside another then like below

```
    var count = "old";
    
    getstatus(statustable).then(function(response){
        console.log("changeing count")
        count = "new";
        console.log(count)

    }).then (() => {
        console.log("old");
    });
```